# Visual Studio Express 2010 References Issue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I accidentally removed the references from one of my projects and then carefully put them back in.  However now I am throwing errors in code the was functioning perfectly so I think I must still be missing a reference unless something else was broken in the process.  Here is the current error:

```
The variable 'button1' is either undeclared or was never assigned.
```

But here is the code in Form1.Designer.cs:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        ...
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(235, 382);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "Generate Report";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        ...
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        ...
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
```

The last seven lines are all throwing this error.  Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

EDIT:  Here is code relevant to the comments:

```
public partial class Severity3RetailNetworkTrackingLog : Form
{
    public Severity3RetailNetworkTrackingLog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
```

Where Form1 has been changed to Severity3RetailNetworkTrackingLog.

Comment: Sounds like button1 is not declared.  There should be a line: Button Button1;

Comment: It is not a problem with your references or you would get an exception related to trying to use the type Button instead of an instance related exception. You seem to be missing your Button declaration. Button button1 = new Button();

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are missing the member variable definition

```
class Form1 {
   /* lots of windows form designer code */

   /* some other member variables */
   System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
}
```

Within your class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that VS Express 2010 was just misbehaving.  I commented out all of the offending code and still got the same errors with the same line numbers.  So I closed and opened VS and everything is back to normal.